# How do I use signals from a QWidget to tell the main window to execute a function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to run a function inputAttendance(AthleteInfo) whenever the enter button is pressed on the confirmPopup window. This function is contained within another file that I import and is not in any of the classes. 
One problem I have is that it seems to run

> self.confirmw.confirmAthlete.connect(inputAttendance(AthleteInfo))

before the signal is even emitted. Once inputAttendance() is done, the entire window closes after I get an error

> argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

I tried looking it up and it possibly could be me not defining a connection type?

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have been stuck on this for quite some while.

Edit: InputAttendance() is a function that updates a spreadsheet that is in another file that I imported but didn't include in the post since it is irrelevant to my question. I have tested the function and it works perfectly so I am certain it is not causing the program to crash but rather how it is called. Sorry for the confusion!

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, 
    QInputDialog, QApplication, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Ex(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        self.le = QLineEdit(self)
        self.le.move(500, 500)
        self.le.returnPressed.connect(self.pushEnter)    

        self.setGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')
        self.show()

    def pushEnter(self):
        text = self.le.text()
        AthleteInfo = getID(text)

        if (AthleteInfo == -1):
            print ("Could nto find that ID")

        else:
            try:
                self.confirmw =confirmPopup("Confirm Window")
            except Exception in e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(10)
            self.confirmw.setGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)
            self.confirmw.show()
            try:

                self.confirmw.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(5)
            try:                   self.confirmw.confirmAthlete.connect(inputAttendance(AthleteInfo))

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(5)

class confirmPopup(QWidget):

    confirmAthlete = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        lblName = QLabel(self.name, self, text = "Press enter to confirm")

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        keyPress = event.text()

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter or event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:

            try:
                #print("Emitting Signal")
                self.confirmAthlete.emit("Yes")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                time.sleep(5)

        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            print("Backspace was pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ex()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is inputAttendance?

Comment: Didn't the answer bellow work? It should work perfectly.

Comment: @Y.Melo Thanks for your response! I am caught up in some work at the moment/ going back to school so I am going to take a look at your reply tomorrow night.

Answer (score -1):

Helloww sir, that's a really nice question, let's summarize in this way.

1. Let's suppose we have two classes, the Widget class and the MainWindow class.
2. The widget will contain two signals, one signal runs a method from itself, the other signal will run a method from the MainWindow.
3. The first signal we will connect inside the widget, emit and run a method from the Widget.
4. The second will be connected inside the MainWindow where we have a widget instance of our class and will run a method from the MainWindow

**Let's have a look in this small example that represents what I just tried to summarize.**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    myWidget = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.myWidget = Widget()

        self.setFixedSize(500,500)
        self.myWidget.setFixedSize(500,500)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.myWidget)

        self.myWidget.signalExecuteAMainWindowFunction.connect(self.mainWindowFunction)

    def mainWindowFunction(self):
        print("running my MAINWINDOW function...")


class Widget(QWidget):

    signalExecuteMyFunction = pyqtSignal()
    signalExecuteAMainWindowFunction = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.signalExecuteMyFunction.connect(self.myFunction)

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.signalExecuteMyFunction.emit()
        super(Widget, self).mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.signalExecuteAMainWindowFunction.emit()
        super(Widget, self).mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent)

    def myFunction(self):
        print("running my WIDGET function...")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***Ps: There are many more beautiful ways to do some things that I've done, like variable names, object orientation and organization, but it's the essence of what you asked that matter. Hope it clarified a little bit more about how it works. :D***